# Upload File and Place in working directory

Tags: javascript, html, angular, upload, file-handling

I am a relative beginner to angular and I am trying to create a web-page that allows users to upload a file, which is then placed within a folder in the working directory.

The upload page component is currently at the path 'uploadtool/frontend/src/app/upload-page/upload-page.component.html'

The destination folder where I want the uploaded files to be saved is 'uploadtool/uploads'

I've searched online for a guide but cant find anything that relates to this specifically.

All i have so far is the upload graphic itself using:

```
<div class='form-group'>
        <label for='file'> Choose File to Upload </label>
        <input type='file id='file' >
</div>
```

Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do that with angular, you should use node.js to save a file to your local folder.

Comment: Do you maybe have a link to a tutorial or guide on how this can be done?

Comment: I watched this tutorial and it helps me to do my task - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srPXMt1Q0nY&list=LL2LVudOSZlZLYx32zDjNpYw&index=25&t=5s